# How to set quotas on GCP cloud endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I need to set up two kinds of quotas for my endpoint:
- a general quota for any client call the endpoint
- a specific quota for a specific client that call my endpoint

From the documentation [https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-configure] I can't find how to do this, better: I understand that I can do only the first point, not the second.

The second point must be implemented in my business logic?
If yes, any kind of suggestions/best practices to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to set a quotas for any client? What is your constraint?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the rate at which applications call you API by setting the quotas on Cloud Endpoints. All the request are tied to the **consumer project**:

> After you configure a quota, Endpoints tracks the number of requests
> per minute per consumer Google Cloud project. Each application that
> calls your API must:
>
> Have a Google Cloud project.
>
> Have enabled your API in their Google Cloud project.
>
> Send an API key. with each request to your API. This
> lets Endpoints identify the Google Cloud project that the calling
> application is associated with and to increment the request counter
> for the Google Cloud project.
>
> For information on configuring an API
> key, see the following:
>
> You can either have your API consumers create
> their own projects in the Google Cloud Console, or you can create the
> projects for them. Because **Endpoints enforces quotas per project**, you
> must have one project for each API consumer.

[Cloud Endpoints: About quotas](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/quotas-overview)